# Probabilities of ending the game at turn $1-5$ and so on?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If from a deck of $52$ cards, one card is selected at random, which is called 'joker' (say, in this instance it is 8 of hearts). Now from the rest of the deck, cards are drawn from top to bottom, one by one, until another card with face value same as 'joker' i.e. 8 hits (class or color of card does not matter here) and the game ends there and then only. What is the probability that game will end in

1. $1-5$ turns
2. $6-10$ turns
3. $11-15$ turns
4. $16-25$ turns
5. $26-30$ turns
6. $31-35$ turns
7. $36-40$ turns
8. $41$ or more turns

To be honest I am not very good in probabilities, but my argument is that it is a case of conditional probabilities, as for case $1$ it should be $3/51+\frac{(3/50)}{48/51}+\frac{3/49}{\text{probability of first two cards not be eight}}+ \frac{3/48}{\text{probability of first three cards not be eight}}+ \frac{3/47}{\text{probability of first four cards not be eight}}$.

Similarly for rest of the cases. Also for the probability of first two/three/four cards not be eight should again be based on conditional probability, right? This way probability of last case must be least among all. It's very tedious to calculate but is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people would not think this problem involved conditional probability, but you are correct that it does. However, in each of your terms you are dividing while you should be multiplying.

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)*P(B|A)$$
Suppose $A$ is the event that the first card is not an 8. $P(A)=\frac{48}{51}$
Suppose $B$ is the event that the second card is an 8.  So $P(B|A)$ is the probability that the second card is an 8, given that the first card has been chosen and was not an 8 (i.e. given that there are now 50 cards left containing three 8s). This means $P(B|A)=\frac{3}{50}$.
So the second term in your expression should be $\frac{48}{51}\frac{3}{50}$. Similarly for all the other terms.

Apart from that mistake, your approach will work. There is however a much easier way.

The probability of the game NOT ending within the first five turns is easy to calculate. It means that the first five cards drawn were all not an 8, and it does not matter what happens after that. This probability is
$$p = \frac{48}{51}\frac{47}{50}\frac{46}{49}\frac{45}{48}\frac{44}{47}$$
The probability that the game does end within the first five turns is then $1-p$.

You can similarly calculate the probability of the game NOT ending in the first 10 turns, and use that and the previous result to get the probability of it ending in 6-10 turns. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest strategy is to find the probability that the game ends exactly after $k$ turns, which is:
$$
p(k)=\frac{\binom31\binom{48}{k-1}(k-1)!}{\binom{51}{k}k!}=\frac{3\binom{48}{k-1}}{k\binom{51}{k}},\tag1
$$
where the numerator counts the sequences with $k-1$ "wrong" cards (in any order) followed by a "good" one and the denominator counts all possible sequences of $k$ cards.

The probability to end the game in turns $k_1$ to $k_2$ will be accordingly:
$$
P(k_1,k_2)=\sum_{k=k_1}^{k_2}p(k).
$$

---

What concerns your expression the "probability of first $k$ cards not be eight" should be a factor rather than a divisor:

$$\begin{align}
3/51&+{(3/50)}\cdot({48/51})\\
&+({3/49})\cdot({\text{probability of first two cards not be eight}})\\
&+ ({3/48})\cdot({\text{probability of first three cards not be eight}})\\
&+ ({3/47})\cdot({\text{probability of first four cards not be eight}}),\end{align}$$
where each term represents $p(k)$ from equation (1).